# GRAV subnavigation

Tags: html, content-management-system, twig, grav

I try to make my first site with [GRAV](http://getgrav.org) CMS.
Now in my `pages-folder` it looks like this:

- home/default.md
- about
- about/seite1/default.md
- about/seite2/default.md

Now, if i put the following code into my html-file, only the main points are showed in the navigation.

```
<nav class="" role="navigation">        
    <div class="">
        <ol class="">
            {% for page in pages.children %}
            {% if page.visible %}
            {% set current_page = (page.active or page.activeChild) ? 'active' : '' %}
            <li class="{{ current_page }}"><a href="{{ page.url }}">{{ page.menu }}</a</li>
            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}                
        </ol>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Is there a way to show all the pages, including subpages in the navigation?

thanks for your answer...

Comment: Are you sure that all pages marked as visible?

Comment: Yes. You can hide elements by putting a _ in front of them, but I don't have any folder / page with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should give you the fist level of children (subpages) in your navigation:

```
<nav class="" role="navigation">        
    <div class="">
        <ol class="">
            {% for page in pages.children %}
                {% if page.visible %}
                    {% set current_page = (page.active or page.activeChild) ? 'active' : '' %}
                    <li class="{{ current_page }}"><a href="{{ page.url }}">{{ page.menu }}</a></li>
                    {% if page.children %}
                        <ol class="">
                        {% for child in page.children %}
                            {% if child.visible %}
                                <li class="{{ current_page }}"><a href="{{ child.url }}">{{ child.menu }}</a></li>
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                        </ol>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}                
        </ol>
    </div>
</nav>
```